# Как в mysqli вывести значение из определенной ячейки?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli, функции

Здравствуйте!

> У меня вопрос у меня есть таблица  matches в этой таблице  5 ячеек 
>   id, team 1,team 2, event, bon. Я написал код, который выводит всю
>   информацию с ячеек лимитом  21

```
function getPost() {
    global $link;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `matches` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 21 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $posts;

}
```

**И что получилось:**[image: типа крутая картинка]

**Как сделать, что бы при переходе на один матч выводилось именно данные этого матча, вот мой код:**

```
function getMatch() {

    global $link;
    $sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM `matches` WHERE 'id'='Вот тут я даже не знаю что придумать'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $matches = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $matches;
}
```

> Со ссылками все хорошо, для каждого матча она своя. К примеру:
>   http://csesports.ru/match.php?m=38.

**Но вот я не знаю как вместить во 2 функцию ссылку на этот же матч, ибо если я вставлю `$match['id']` в функцию `getMatch()` в строчку `WHERE id = ''` то она начинает ругаться. Как можно это пофиксить?)**

Comment: Id матча передавайте в функцию как параметр

Comment: заголовок вопроса переформулируйте, он не должен разъяснять условия и прочее, он должен кратко и ясно обозначать проблему

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `matches` WHERE 'id'=". (int)$_GET['m'];
```

Самый быстрый способ, Если `m` - это id твоего матча

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51932/discussion-on-answer-by-andrii---mysqli-----).